# MVC3 call controller method from ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Search/GetNewData"  //Controller/ActionMethod
   ---snip---
)};
```

This works fine when run via localhost, however when it is deployed, it cannot find the controller method.  I think it's probably a routing problem?  But, with only a small limited knowledge using ASP.net, I would appreciate some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app running in a Virtual Directory?

Comment: There might be a problem with virtual directories in you deployment environment? Fire up Fiddler and inspect the request being made and where it goes. Make sure you can issue a request to `/Search/GetNewData`

Comment: I'm not sure Bertrand.  It has been deployed by a colleague on an internal works server.

Comment: Spoke with my team lead, and yes we are running on a virtual directory.  Any tips on how this should be handled?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet would work for both virtual directories and web sites.

```
var baseUri = '@Url.Content("~/")';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUri + "Search/GetNewData"  //Controller/ActionMethod
   ---snip---
)};
```

You can also define the `baseUri` variable in  your layout (above all `<script` tags) to be able to use it in all included javascripts.

Comment: no, but the OPs problem seems to be root vs virtual dir. And it will work for that.

Comment: I am using a seperate JS file, and the razor syntax will not work there.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Darren Young: Read my answer again, especially the last sentence

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to specify the URL directly in your JavaScript.

You *need* to use helpers; otherwise if you change your routes, you'll have to rewrite all the URLS in your JavaScript code. Also, it won't work if your website is hosted in a IIS virtual directory (what seems to be the issue here).

You have a couple solutions here, if your JavaScript code is embedded inside a view, simply use

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetNewData", "Search")'
)};
```

If it's inside an external JavaScript file, you could, for example, use HTML5 `data-*` attributes to share the URL to your JavaScript code.

For example:

```
<div id="foo" data-update-url="@Url.Action("GetNewData", "Search")">
</div>
```

Then the JavaScript code would be something like

```
var updateDiv = $('#foo');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: updateDiv.data('update-url'),
    success: function(data) {
       updateDiv.append(data);
    }
)};
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an ideal solution, unfortunately I didn't set the project up to use HTML 5 semantics!

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as you can access them with jQuery.

Comment: I get an error saying that the data-* attribute is not a valid member of div.  I thought this may have been due to not having HTML5 semantics?  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the validation schema is probably just set to HTML4.01, you can change that anytime, there's a drop down list somewhere in Visual Studio to do so.

Comment: I think I may need to update VS2010 then, as that option is not in the drop down.  I think i'll need to grab SP1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install FireBug for FireFox. Open .NET panel and Console panels. Request the URL to see whether you get any errors. If none found, then learn to use a debugger. This is by no means a quick fix, but it will help you in the future to fix these sort of problems yourself. Good luck.